# Package was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: c++, makefile, configure

I am trying to install [this](https://gitlab.com/german.tischler/biobambam2) package on ubuntu 18.04. The installation instructions say that the installation command should look like the following:

```
- autoreconf -i -f
- ./configure --with-libmaus2=${LIBMAUSPREFIX} \
    --prefix=${HOME}/biobambam2
- make install
```

The first line seems to work without any errors. When I try to run the second line like so:

```
./configure --with-libmaus2=/SOFT/libmaus2-2.0.794-release-20210706224245/ --prefix=/SOFT/biobambam2-2.0.182-release-20210412001032/
```

I get the following error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libmaus2 >= 2.0.774) were not met:

Package libmaus2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libmaus2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'libmaus2', required by 'world', not found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables libmaus2_CFLAGS
and libmaus2_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I understand that `./configure` does not see the library directory I provided, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to install correctly libmaus2 and set correctly  PKG_CONFIG_PATH :

1. configure and compile libmaus2 this way : `./configure --prefix=/SOFT/libmaus2 && make -j8 install`
2. `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/SOFT/libmaus2/lib/pkgconfig`
3. `./configure --prefix=/SOFT/biobambam2 && make -j8 install`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Except the directory should be just /SOFT/libmaus2-2.0.794-release-20210706224245. There is no lib folder there, but libmaus2.pc file is.

Comment: On second thought it's not working. It seemed to be compiling but for some reason, I can't reproduce it. Now I am getting this error: `checking for libmaus2... yes
checking whether we can compile a program using libmaus2... no
configure: error: Required libmaus2 is not available.`

Comment: try in https://gitlab.com/german.tischler/biobambam2/-/blob/master/configure.ac#L184 replacing LIBS with LDFAGS. Relaunch autoconf -vif before launching configure

Comment: and more precisely : LDFLAGS="${LDFLAGS} ${libmaus2_LIBS}"

Comment: Same error. I was using autoreconf, because autoconf -vif exited with invalid option message.

Comment: yes, sorry, autoreconf. Paste config.log in pastebin.com

Comment: error is line 549 of your paste. Tell me where the file ArgInfo.hpp is, please

Comment: It's here: ./libmaus2-2.0.794-release-20210706224245/src/libmaus2/util/ArgInfo.hpp

Comment: how did you install libmaus2 ? Because there is definitely something wrong there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234722/discussion-between-yky-and-vtorri).

Answer (score 1):

In general, install proper developer version of the library would work.

"Configure" searches the required library with something like:

```
    pkg-config --modversion libmaus2
```

Typically, Ubuntu distributes two versions: one is the normal lib. The other is a developer version with pc file and header files etc for pkg-config, and with added "-dev" to the pkg name. You can check available library as

```
    apt-cache search libmaus
```

that returns (on my system Ubuntu 22)

```
    libmaus2-2
    libmaus2-dev
```

If install libmaus2-dev, the pc file named libmaus2.pc would get installed to, for example, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libmaus2.pc
Install libmaus2 would not get that.

If you have to build libmaus yourself and install to a path not in pkg-config search paths, do something like

```
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/special/path/to/pkgconfig:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}
```

NOTE: Use the following to check pkg-config search paths:

```
    pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config
```