# Can't figure out how to link C++ package I want to compile to a library

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, configure

I want to compile [biobambam2](https://gitlab.com/german.tischler/biobambam2) package which is dependent on [libmaus2](https://gitlab.com/german.tischler/libmaus2) library. Both are separate folders in one directory. I compiled libmaus2 and libmaus2.pc file is in its base directory. Now if I try to compile biobambam2 using this command:

```
- autoreconf -i -f
- ./configure --with-libmaus2=/SOFT/libmaus2-2.0.794-release-20210706224245 \
    --prefix=/SOFT/biobambam2-2.0.182-release-20210412001032
- make install
```

I get the following error:

```
...
configure: error: Package requirements (libmaus2 >= 2.0.774) were not met:

Package libmaus2 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libmaus2.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'libmaus2', required by 'world', not found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables libmaus2_CFLAGS
and libmaus2_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

If I try to manually set PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable like so:

```
autoreconf -i -f && \
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/SOFT/libmaus2-2.0.794-release-20210706224245/:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH" && \
./configure --prefix=/SOFT/biobambam2-2.0.182-release-20210412001032/ && \
make install
```

The error looks like this:

```
...
checking for libmaus2... yes
checking whether we can compile a program using libmaus2... no
configure: error: Required libmaus2 is not available.
```

Can anyone advise me on how to solve this? I've been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: Examples: **1**. `./configure PKG_CONFIG_PATH=.....` --prefix and other options. ......... ...... **2**. `export PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=[path-to-directory-with-libmaus2.pc]`

Comment: This didn't work

Comment: I am trying to configure Docker with Ubuntu 18.04 image as a base.

Comment: I manually edited libmaus2.pc file and it seems to be working. Thanks a lot. I am now recompiling and will get back to you, in case you want to post a solution to the problem.

Comment: It thought it worked because I was running ./configure script in the wrong directory. So yep, it is still not working.

Comment: You have an unusual setup. Default build directory is `/home/name/tmp/` and if configuring libmaus2 to `--prefix=/usr/ --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`     there's no issues at all with building  biobambam2 .

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I've got help from another thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68325368/package-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path/68325934#68325934

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 example : Build in /home/*name*/tmp/

`sudo apt install python3-pygments libsnappy-dev libgmp-dev`

Downloaded from Ubuntu 20.04 https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libdeflate-dev →
`sudo gdebi libdeflate0_1.5-3_amd64.deb && sudo gdebi libdeflate-dev_1.5-3_amd64.deb`

Installed gcc94-c++_9.4.0-9_amd64.deb https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xTbHe8ktjKR2gSmQ0Qcw0WEuMoKR8s_w/view?usp=sharing → `sudo gdebi gcc94-c++_9.4.0-9_amd64.deb`

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/german.tischler/libmaus2.git
cd libmaus2/
libtoolize && aclocal && autoheader && automake --add-missing && autoconf
export CC=gcc94 CXX=g++94 && ./configure --prefix=/usr libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
make
sudo make install-strip
```

---

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/german.tischler/biobambam2.git
cd biobambam2/
libtoolize && aclocal && autoheader && automake --add-missing && autoconf
export CC=gcc94 CXX=g++94 && ./configure
make
sudo make install-strip
```

No errors.